# Callback and update data

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, refresh, reload

I have 3 Activity

Activity 1 show listview

Activity 2 show detailItem (**activity 3 will call in activity 2**)

Activity 3 create new task

I want when create success in activity 3 then callback activity 1 and update data

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution for very large projects, but:

You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to send event to from a place to another.

First make the message class:

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

Send data from anywhere using:

```
 EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

And receive it by registering the activity to event bus:

```
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```

Add this to activity to be notified when message was received:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

Add it to gradle using it's dependency code:

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

Comment: Ok! I will try. Tks

Comment: I have solution to handler my problem. Tks for answer